# Does scope change at all when including class files in a class method in PHP?

Tags: php, class, scope, php-include

I feel silly asking but can I check with the experts about the behaviour of including inside a class method.

When I use `require_once` to include class definition files inside a class method are there any gotchas I need to be aware of. I am thinking of an autoloading method on a factory class but really any time the a method does include or require.

My expectation is that it should be exactly the same as if I had simply included them at the start in, say, an include file. Am I right? I only ask as when you include a file in a class method it inherits the method scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to watch out for is scoping of global variables.  By example:

**File: a.php**

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
```

**File: b.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'a.php';
echo $foo;
```

**File: c.php**

```
<?php
load_foo();
show_foo();

function load_foo() {
  require_once 'a.php';
}
function show_foo() {
  require_once 'b.php';
}
```

Now if you run `b.php` directly (e.g. `php b.php`) you will get the proper output:

```
bar
```

However, if you run `c.php` you get this:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: foo in C:\temp\b.php on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\temp\c.php:0
PHP   2. show_foo() C:\temp\c.php:3
PHP   3. require_once() C:\temp\c.php:9
```

The reason for the error is that inside `c.php` we load `a.php` within the function `load_foo()`.  This causes the variable `$foo` to be scoped as a *local* variable for function `load_foo()` whereas otherwise it would be a global variable.  Then when `show_foo()` is called it loads `b.php`, which skips the `require_once` (since we already loaded `a.php`) and then tries to print `$foo`.  But it can't, because `$foo` isn't defined anymore.  It went out of scope when we `load_foo()` exited.

So, bringing it back to your original question - if you use autoload and the autoload happens in a function/method context, global variables are going to be scoped locally as in the example above.  If you absolutely need to use global variables, make sure you use the `global` keyword before you define them (that would be `global $foo` as the first line of `a.php` above) and before you use them (again, `global $foo` after the `require_once` in `b.php`).